# Postgresql NOT NULL AND <> '' vs NOT NULL OR <> ''

Tags: postgresql, null, logical-operators, comparison-operators

I have read lots about the **difference between NOT NULL vs <>''**

The best explanation I found for it was in:

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTilEsUTIeUkZCX9Vc14kciFiuvFBRRE-yen4K_Zi@mail.gmail.com which states:

> NULL means the question hasn't been answered yet, thus there is no
>   answer, there may be an answer once it is provided so you can't really
>   say the answer is empty. Empty would mean the answer has been given and
>   the answer is empty.

For the table that I am working on, I was trying to filter results for **valid postcodes only** (postcode is a VARCHAR in this specific table), I tried the following:

```
SELECT postcode FROM customer_table_1 
WHERE postcode IS NOT NULL OR postcode <> '';
```

However this gives some blank postcodes in my results. Breaking this down ...

```
SELECT postcode FROM customer_table_1 
WHERE postcode IS NOT NULL;
```

gives some blank postcodes whereas

```
SELECT postcode FROM customer_table_1 
WHERE postcode <>'';
```

only gives valid postcodes in the result. Therefore the IS NOT NULL part of the query isn't doing what I thought it was.

As part of a more complicated query, I have previously used:

```
SELECT postcode FROM customer_table_1 
WHERE postcode IS NOT NULL AND postcode <> '';
```

and have achieved the desired result. However I have always thought it should be

```
SELECT postcode FROM customer_table_1 
WHERE postcode IS NOT NULL OR postcode <> '';
```

**Because I am looking for all records that have a valid postcode (i.e. are NOT NULL or NOT empty strings) should these not be connected with an OR statement rather than an AND? I'm not looking for postcodes that are both NULL and empty strings, just one or the other.**

Apologies if this is a stupid question, using an AND doesn't seem logical to me and I don't want to blindly do something without understanding the process behind the result. I thought I fully understood the difference between NOT NULL and <>'' but as with most things Postgres related, the more I delve into it the more I realize I don't actually know!

Comment: `arg != val1 or arg != val2` is always true except if `arg` is `null` or if `val1 = val2` If `postcode` is not null then the second expression of the `or` operator can be ignored. So you guess about using `and` is right. Or `not (postcode is null or postcode = '')`. Yet another approach: `nullif(postcode,'') is not null` or `coalesce(postcode, '') <> ''` but this is require to tune an indexes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would benefit from knowing [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) which is fundamental to Boolean logic.

In this case, your condition is not what you expressed as:

```
(NOT NULL) OR (NOT EMPTY)
```

but is actually:

```
NOT (NULL OR EMPTY)
```

which expanded out according to De Morgan actually becomes:

```
(NOT NULL) AND (NOT EMPTY)
```

hence why `AND` is the correct (and indeed "logical") operator.

Comment: Thanks Alnitak , that really cleared that up for me. Thanks to everyone else as well, I think I have gotten my head around it now!

Answer (score 2):

When you `or` two expressions the result will be `true` when at least one of them is `true`:

```
select true or false;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

In your case whenever `postcode` `is not null` the result will be `true`. An empty `postcode` `is not null` so it will be returned:

```
select 
    '' is not null, -- empty is not null
    '' <> '',       -- false
    '' is not null or '' <> '' -- (true or false) is true
 ;
 ?column? | ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------+----------
 t        | f        | t
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT postcode FROM customer_table_1 WHERE postcode IS NOT NULL AND postcode != ''
```

This seems to do the work

Answer (score 0):

In plain English... You're looking for records that fulfill **BOTH** these conditions: `(postcode IS NOT NULL)` **AND** `(postcode <> '')`.

Fulfilling just `(postcode IS NOT NULL)` **OR** just `(postcode <> '')` is not enough.